# Filter search for <ul>

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, html-lists, textinput

I have a list of users as well:

```
<ul>
<li class="thumb selectable arrow light" style="margin-bottom:-5px;"
data-image="http://cdn.tapquo.com/lungo/icon-144.png">
<strong class="name">Peter <font data-count="0" style="position:relative;top:-2px;"> </font></strong> 
<small class="description">Hi!</small> 
</li>
...
</ul>
```

what I want is a text input each time you write a letter to display only users that start with that letter or that they might have the name. As I can do? It is with jquery but not as ...

Comment: i don't really get what you want. plus whathaveyoudone? as always

Comment: as far as i undersand. you have a list of users and a text input. when we start typing, you want the users that match to showup somewhere

Comment: I'm absolutely confuzzled. Can you please specify in steps what you want to achieve? Do you want an `input` field that has a listener and checks if each letter inserted in it starts with a letter?

Comment: So what you say btevfik, I have a list of users and an input whenever users enter a letter not containing those letters disappear and remain only those that match.

Comment: As an example of this product filter without having to use the jquerymobile http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0/docs/widgets/listviews/#list-filter

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Here is a `input` that filters a `<ul>` based on the value in pure JavaScript. It works by handling the `onkeyup` and then getting the `<li>`s and comparing their inner element `.name` with the filter text.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BJ5Vu/63/)

[image]

```
var input = document.getElementById('input');
input.onkeyup = function () {
    var filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    var lis = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
    for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
        var name = lis[i].getElementsByClassName('name')[0].innerHTML;
        if (name.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) == 0) 
            lis[i].style.display = 'list-item';
        else
            lis[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably should use `display = 'list-item';`

Comment: Please extend the answer to search for name that matches either first name or last name. Should display if search matches any of the names(first or last). In the above case 'Andrew' or 'Hi'.

Comment: To search for matches anywhere in the in the word, use `if (name.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) != -1)` instead. `-1` is used to denote no matches.

Answer (score 2):

alterei o codigo do Daniel Imms pra procurar qualquer parte do nome
e funciona com classes

```
var input = document.getElementById('seachUser');
input.onkeyup = function () {
    var filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    var lis = document.getElementsByClassName('listUser');
    for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
        var name = lis[i].getElementsByClassName('userName')[0].innerHTML;
        if (name.toUpperCase().includes(filter)) 
            lis[i].style.display = 'list-item';
        else
            lis[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

So you have a collection of list items inside an unordered list like this.

```
<div class="some-input-field-class">
   <input type="text" name="filter" id="filter">
   <label for="filter">Filter Names</label>
</div>

<ul class="my-user-collection">
  <li class="thumb selectable arrow light" style="margin-bottom:-5px;"
  data-image="http://cdn.tapquo.com/lungo/icon-144.png">
  <strong class="name">Peter <font data-count="0" style="position:relative;top:-2px;"> </font></strong> 
  <small class="description">Hi!</small> 
  </li>
  ...
</ul>
```

You can add this in your javascript file. But you will need to load the event listener too. You probably have a few events so just do what you need to do. Maybe add it to another function where you load the rest of your event listeners.

```
// Load the event listener
document.querySelector('#filter').addEventListener('keyup', filterNames);
```

Function to iterate through the li by targeting the class, iterate through the array since we use querySelectorAll and NOT getElementByID. -1 means no match.

```
function filterNames(e) {
  const text = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
  document.querySelectorAll('.selectable').forEach(
    function(name) {
      let item = name.firstChild.textContent;
      if (item.toLowerCase().indexOf(text) != -1) {
        name.style.display = 'block';
      } else {
        name.style.display = 'none';
      }
    }
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this if you are parsing the cls to HTML:

```
var input = document.getElementById('myInput');
input.onkeyup = function () {
  var filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  var lis = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
  for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
    var name = lis[i].innerText;
    if (name.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) == 0) 
      lis[i].style.display = 'list-item';
    else
      lis[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```